# Queue File Copy Operation using C# Queue<MethodInvoker>

Tags: c#, queue, filecopy

I'm trying to create a file copy application. I have a BackgroudWorker doing the work and it works fine so far. How it works, I have a form, Source and Destination Folder fields and a Copy button. The Copy button triggers the Copy operation using the BackgroundWorker. The Progressbar gets updated etc. Now I need to implemet a queue type of operation. I need to add other Source and Destination Copy operation and add it to the queue. I tried using the following:

```
Queue<MethodInvoker> MyQueue = new Queue<MethodInvoker>();

        MyQueue.Enqueue(new MethodInvoker(() =>CopyStuff(1)));
        MyQueue.Enqueue(new MethodInvoker(() =>CopyStuff(2)));

        MethodInvoker bb = MyQueue.Dequeue(); //(I Forgot this part)
        bb();
        bb = MyQueue.Dequeue();
        bb();
```

<s>The problem is, because it's a BackgroundWorker, it does not wait for the first operation to complete. Any suggestions on how to go about this?</s>
After fixing my code it works, except for it running on the UI thread, locking controls.

**Update 1:**

This works, but runs on main thread, user can't use controls while it's running:

```
        BlockingCollection<MethodInvoker> bCollection = new BlockingCollection<MethodInvoker>(boundedCapacity: 2);
        Task producerThread = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            {

                bCollection.Add(CopyStuff);
            }

            bCollection.CompleteAdding();
        });

        foreach (MethodInvoker item in bCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            BeginInvoke(item);
        }
```

**Update 2:**

Works in a Console App, but not a Windows Forms Application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncCopy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class AsyncCopy
        {
            private static Queue<Action> MyQueue = new Queue<Action>();

            public async Task EnqueueAndCopy(Action[] actionList)
            {
                foreach (var action in actionList)
                {
                    MyQueue.Enqueue(action);
                }
                while (MyQueue.TryDequeue(out var copyAction)) //Here's the problem on Windows Form Applivcation
                {
                    //If the copyaction is itself async, await directly on the method here instead of running the action in a Task
                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(copyAction);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var asyncCopy = new AsyncCopy();
            //In a typical usage, this will call be awaited
            //In your case, make this call from a async method and call it from the UI thread
            asyncCopy.EnqueueAndCopy(
                new Action[] {
                () => CopyStuff (1),
                () => CopyStuff (2)
                }
            );

            //Loop to confirm the processing is asynchronous
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }
        //Copy process simulation
        static void CopyStuff(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Copying {i}");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Copied {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to Queue the Copy process asynchronously as the other copies are processing, I would recommend a producer consumer pattern. Refer https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1407/producer-consumer-pattern-dotnet-csharp

But a simple async await would work in your case as well

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Threading;

   namespace stackoverflow {
   class Program {

    static void Main (string[] args) {
        var asyncCopy = new AsyncCopy ();
        //In a typical usage, this will call be awaited
        //In your case, make this call from a async method and call it from the UI thread
        asyncCopy.EnqueueAndCopy (
            new Action[] {
                () => CopyStuff (1),
                () => CopyStuff (2)
            }
        );

        //Loop to confirm the processing is asynchronous
        for(int i=0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
    }
    //Copy process simulation
    static void CopyStuff (int i) {
        Console.WriteLine ($"Copying {i}");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine ($"Copied {i}");
    }

}

public class AsyncCopy {
    private static Queue<Action> MyQueue = new Queue<Action> ();

    public async Task EnqueueAndCopy (Action[] actionList) {
        foreach (var action in actionList) {
            MyQueue.Enqueue (action);
        }
        while (MyQueue.TryDequeue (out var copyAction)) {
            //If the copyaction is itself async, await directly on the method here instead of running the action in a Task
            await Task.Factory.StartNew (copyAction);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Update

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task CopyAsync(IEnumerable<Action> actionList)
    {
        foreach (var action in actionList)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
        }
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CopyAsync(
            new Action[]
            {
                () => CopyStuff(1),
                () => CopyStuff(2)
            });
    }

    //Copy process simulation
    static void CopyStuff(int i)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File Copied {0}", i));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Vishwa, thanks for the help. However I'm getting this error: 'Queue<MethodInvoker>' does not contain a definition for 'TryDequeue' and no extension method 'TryDequeue' accepting a first argument of type 'Queue<MethodInvoker>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: do you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` in your references . This has the `Queue` data structure

Comment: Yes, I do have the reference.I tried this: [link](http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-blockingcollection) with a modification. It works, but runs on the main UI thread so no other controls are available to the user.

Comment: I've updated the code as a fully functional snippet with simulation of copy process. Included a for loop after calling the copy process to confirm its running asynchronously. A `BlockingCollection` is not needed since we are not working in the queue simultaneously from different threads. `Action` is used instead of `MethodInvoker`

Comment: Thank You Vishwa. Your solution works in a Console App, but getting an error on `while (MyQueue.TryDequeue(out var copyAction))` when using it in a Windows Forms Application **(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Can you provide the whole code file that you are using? Also which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Check Update 2 Vishwa.

Comment: Check the updated code. I believe you are using a old .NET framework version

Comment: The Net Framework is ver 4.6, also tried 4.7.2. Still has the same error with updated code too. Getting **'Queue<Action>' does not contain a definition for 'TryDequeue' and no accessible extension method 'TryDequeue' accepting a first argument of type 'Queue<Action>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**